# Redirect to user page when logged in

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm a student and noob on programming. I just want this code to be able to redirect to my user index.php if the userlevel that has been logged in is not an admin. Currently it goes to my admin dashboard which I copied from a site and it works. Here's my sample code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: dashboard.php");
  exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: admin/dashboard.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $password_err = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;}
        .wrapper{ width: 400px; padding: 20px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: black; color: white; margin-top: 80px;}
        .center { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 60%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <br>
      <img alt="logo" src="logo.png" class="center"/>
      <h2 align="center">Secret Cafe Billing System</h2>

        <p align="center">Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div align="center" class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <br><br>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just edited the error message both on username and password if entered an invalid credentials because our adviser wanted to have a general error on both and not specified on which input the user got the wrong credentials. Tweaked it and thankfully it worked. Please help.

Comment: Welcome. Have you done anything to solve this or are you asking us to do this task for you? Before you redirect to the dashboard, check the user level and redirect to a different page.

Comment: thank you @kerbholz I tried this http://codewithawa.com/posts/admin-and-user-login-in-php-and-mysql-database but unable to managed it to work and I find it hard to analize because they have different approach from my originally copied log in work. Basically I needed you guys to help me add codes here. Sorry

Comment: As the page says, send "user_type" to log as admin. You can play with this variable to know if is user or admin.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out thankfully. Here's my answer.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: dashboard.php");
  exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, userlvl, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $userlvl, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            if ($userlvl == 'Admin') {


                                // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: admin/dashboard.php");
                            } else {



                                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
                                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: admin/billing.php");
                            }


                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $password_err = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;}
        .wrapper{ width: 400px; padding: 20px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: black; color: white; margin-top: 80px;}
        .center { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 60%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <br>
      <img alt="logo" src="logo.png" class="center"/>
      <h2 align="center">Secret Cafe Billing System</h2>

        <p align="center">Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div align="center" class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <br><br>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```